# .Net 7.0 OData WebApi returns 200 and does nothing

Tags: .net-core, authorization, odata

I have an OData API using Authorization that was working previously and since updating the project to .Net 7.0 everything is working except when Authorization is configured on the routes I get a 200 OK code but nothing happens. The kicker is, on that route there is no 200. It's either 204 or 404.

Program.cs -

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options => options
        .AddRouteComponents("odata/v1", new ReviewsEntityDataModel().GetEntityDataModel())        
            .Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Count().SetMaxTop(5)
        );

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthorityServer") ?? "https://sts.<truncated>";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidTypes = new[] { "at+jwt" };
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("api.read", policy =>
    {
        //policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "reviews.api.read");
    });

    options.AddPolicy("api.readwrite", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "reviews.api.readwrite");
    });

    options.AddPolicy("api.delete", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "reviews.api.delete");
    });

});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMiddleware<UserScopeMiddleware>();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapHealthChecks("health").AllowAnonymous();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
app.Run();
```

CategoriesController.cs

```
public class CategoriesController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly ReviewsDbContext _reviewsDbContext;
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ILogger<CategoriesController> _logger;

        public CategoriesController(ReviewsDbContext reviewsDbContext, IConfiguration iConfig, ILogger<CategoriesController> logger)
        {
            _reviewsDbContext = reviewsDbContext
                ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reviewsDbContext));

            _configuration = iConfig;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        // DELETE: ~/Categories(key)
        [Authorize(Policy = "api.delete")]
        [HttpDelete("odata/v1/Categories({key})")]
        public IActionResult DeleteOneCategory(int key)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug(0, "Trying to delete category");
            var currentCategory = _reviewsDbContext.Categories
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.CategoryId == key);

            if (currentCategory == null)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug(1, "category not found");
                return NotFound();
            }

            _reviewsDbContext.Categories.Remove(currentCategory);
            _reviewsDbContext.SaveChanges();
            _logger.LogDebug(0, "category deleted");
            return NoContent();
        }
```

Example OAuth2.0 Token used for accessing the API

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "6F0D8328F018AE7684342865EF0F4438",
  "typ": "at+jwt"
}

{
  "iss": "https://sts.<redacted>",
  "nbf": 1681293993,
  "iat": 1681293993,
  "exp": 1681297593,
  "aud": "https://sts.<redacted>/resources",
  "scope": [
    "reviews.api.delete",
    "reviews.api.readwrite"
  ],
  "client_id": "reviews.api.access",
  "jti": "32272B8522A0CC53B23A7E05218417F7"
}
```

If I take off [Authorize] from the route on the controller than everything works as expected.

I'm at a loss to why the API is returning 200 and I don't appear to have any other routes that would match.

Any insights welcome!